# How do I install VMware player on a Mac os X?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I went to their site, and downloaded a .bundle which automagically turned into a .txt file after downloading.

Long story short, I can't run the txt file because I guess Mountain Lion Mac os X isn't a strict Linux box and is missing some core components to do that type of installation.

Does anyone know how to install VMware?

Comment: Just so you know, Mac OS is a derivative of BSD, not Linux. Both BSD and Linux are UNIX-based, but it would be incorrect to say that Mac OS, or even BSD, are based on Linux. So not only is it not a strict Linux box, it's not Linux at all...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no version of VMware Player for OS X. Neither the GNU/Linux version nor the version from FreeBSD ports will work. Instead, VMware sells a Mac version of their product called [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html).

If you don't want to purchase VMware Fusion, you can:

- Use Boot camp to some other OS. The OS itself should run fine.
- Use boot camp and run vmplayer from the other OS. (Untested since I do not have a OS/X host)
- Use other products such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com). VirtualBox can use virtual hard disks in VMware's VMDK format ([like so](http://techathlon.com/how-to-run-a-vmdk-file-in-oracle-virtualbox/)).

Comment: VirtualBox is great.  Parallels just about forces you to upgrade (pay more $$$) with every update, and has "value add" features that are more trouble than they are worth.  And VirtualBox is free.

Comment: VirtualBox is great. I used it in mac, install win 7 to read a DVD which can only be read in windows (autorun).

Answer (score 0):

[VMWare Fusion 12 Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/fusion-evaluation.html) is now available for free (personal use license) but works only on macOS Catalina 10.15+ and above.